# Bootstrap 5 modal with background interaction

Tags: bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

In specifically Bootstrap 5 I am trying to create a modal with no backdrop that will still allow interactivity with the background of the webpage (You can highlight text or scroll the page while the modal is open). Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried using css to hide the .modal-backdrop and also specifying backdrop="false" when creating the modal. While that does remove the dark backdrop the background is still unusable. These things seem to work in Bootstrap 4 but not 5.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it in Bootstrap 5. I have added all the comments where necessary. If you have any question feel free to ask.

```js
// prevent scrolling on modal closure
function disableScroll() {
    scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;                                    
    scrollLeft = window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft;            

    window.onscroll = function() {
        window.scrollTo(scrollLeft, scrollTop);
        window.onscroll = function() {};
    };
}
```

```css
/* Hiding the backdrop */
.modal-backdrop{
    display: none;
}

/* Enable scrolling  */
.modal-open {
    /* overflow: hidden; (default) */
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
        Launch demo modal
    </button>
    
    <!-- Modal --> 
    <!-- data-bs-backdrop="static" <<= attribute is added to prevent modal outside click closure -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-bs-backdrop="static">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <!-- Adding inline event handler for modal close =>>  onclick="disableScroll()" -->
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" onclick="disableScroll()"></button>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                ...
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                <!-- Adding inline event handler for modal close -->
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal" onclick="disableScroll()">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Content for scrolling -->
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 3000px; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;"> Content </div>

    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
```